# How do you transition on both side of x-axis (+ve and -ve)?

Tags: html, css

I have a button which on hover will change it's width from `50px` to `300px`.But it's only doing so on one side(either positive or negative).I want it to change it's width to `300px` with `150px` on either side.

```css
.container-2 {
  width: 300px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
}
.container-2 #search {
  width: 50px;
  -webkit-transition: width .55s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: widtg .55s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: width .55s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: width .55s ease-in-out;
}
.container-2:hover #search {
  outline: none;
  width: 300px;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="container-2">
      <span class="icon">
          <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </span>
      <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search Wikipedia" />

    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Place button in center of container, and then add `transform-origin: 50% 50%;` on button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fiddle using two different implementations. The first is with the original centering trick. The second is with flex-box. If you can get away with it, use the flex.

Here is the CSS without using flexbox:

```
#container-1 {
  text-align: center;
}
#button-1 {
  margin: auto;
}
```

And this is it with flexbox:

```
#container-2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

[JSFiddle with CSS centering implementations](https://jsfiddle.net/taystack/j466n3gu/)

Comment: looks like flex it is!